# Create a matrix from multiple input files in C++ or Python

Tags: c++, python, matrix

We have a fluorescence spectrometer that outputs its fluorescence data in an uncomfortable/stupid manner for further processing. That is, there are 55 lines of comments and information before the actual data starts. Line 55 then starts with the emission wavelengths in column 1 and fluorescence value in column 2 seperated by a tab limiter. Among the comments, there is also the excitation wavelength in line 22. The files look something like this (the line numbers are not part of the file. I just added them for clarity):

```
Line 1   Stefan
Line 2   Date: 23.1.2012
Line 3   WS_40#01.SP
Line 4   ...
Line 22  240
Line 23  ...   
Line 55  300.000000 62.237799  
Line 56  300.500000 59.904189  
Line 57  301.000000 58.901731  
Line 58  ...
Line 656 600.5      23.900000
```

There is one file for each excitation wavelength, which makes 44 files in total for one sample (excitation from 240 to 455 nm in 5 nm steps). The general filename for the 44 spectras is stored in a file called "filename.txt". The 44 files are named numerically, that is for example FILENAME#01.sp, FILENAME#02.sp,..., FILENAME#44.sp

Goal:
I would like to create one matrix from these 44 files that looks like this (ideally, the excitation wavelength is taken from line 22 but the column names could also be created manually, since they are always the same):

```
         240   245   250  ...    455 
300.0  62.23  34.4   ...  ...   23.5
300.5  59.90  23.7   ...  ...   19.5
301.0  58.90  23.7   ...  ...   34.8
...      ...   ...   ...  ...
600.5  23.90   ...   ...  ...
```

Finally, the matrix should be stored in a file called filename.csv

How is this feasible using C++ or Python?

The thing is that I already programmed a solution for this in R. But we would like to have an .exe-file for this, so that the lab technicians can do this task without getting familiar with R. It would really help our lab to get important things done.

Unfortunately, I don't have any good python or c++ code to start from.

Please let me know if the question is somehow unclear. In this case I will add some information or rephrase the question.

Any direct help or linkage to other websites/posts is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use the standard template library to read and write `std::string`s from text files. For example:

```
ifstream filenames ("filename.txt", ifstream::in);
```

That creates an object to read from the "filename.txt" file. You can get each line from the file by doing the following:

```
while (!filenames.eof ())
{
    std::string nextFile;
    filenames.getline (nextFile); // Note, you may have to #include <string> here
    // Do something with nextFile here, like open it and read from it, or put it in an array.
}
```

and when you're done reading the file:

```
filenames.close ();
```

You can use the same technique to read each line from each of the 44 files.

Answer (score 0):

For a day-to-day data analysis in a similar to R manner you could use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) Python library.

To convert the Python script to an .exe-file you could use [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial).

To simplify creation of an executable you could write the script using only Python standard library, [example](https://gist.github.com/45188c014c1b262983ce).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, code, and helpful links. Special thanks to J.F. Sebastian who wrote the python code for this task. Unfortunately, the code gets stuck on line 40 with the following error message: **ValueError: could not convert string to float:**. Here you can download some example files: [file#1](http://almost-published.com/files/WS_40%2301.sp) and [file#2](http://almost-published.com/files/WS_40%2302.sp) and [filename.txt](http://almost-published.com/files/filename.txt). Thanks again for your time and help. I really appreciate it. Stefan

Comment: @Strohmi: there are empty lines at the end. They should be skipped while populating `fluorescenes` dictionaries, [example](https://gist.github.com/45188c014c1b262983ce). If you can't make such changes yourself then start with [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut).